# How to add a custom function/method in sqlalchemy model to do CRUD operations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Below I have a `Flask-SQLAlchemy` model for the table `User`.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

    def __init__(self):
        #self.name = name
        self.name = None

    def add_user(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Here `add_user` is a custom method. So if I call the `add_user` method it should add the name to the `User` table.

Likewise how do I write custom methods for CRUD operations in that model itself?

Comment: A bit late, but I would suggest __not doing this__.  The traditional wisdom here is to use MVC, meaning create another class called 'UserController' and have that interact with the model object.  This practice is __highly recommended__.  While I am the first person to suggest taking shortcuts in small projects and prototypes, this is not something you want to do if it will become part of a larger build.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a classmethod to accomplish this.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kw):
        obj = cls(**kw)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
```

This way you can use `User.create(name="kumaran")` to create a new user that will be committed to the database.

Better yet, it is a great idea to create a mixin for this method and others like it so that the functionality can be easily reused in your other models:

```
class BaseMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kw):
        obj = cls(**kw)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
```

You can then reuse this functionality in your models by using multiple inheritance, like so:

```
class User(BaseMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Comment: Where does the database session come from in this example? Is it good practice to have one global `db.session` object used by methods, as seems to be the case here?

Comment: @Hey Yes that is a typical practice. I run a single session if I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy and share it amongst all my classes. Each class has its own functions or methods as showed above which I wrap in try: except: finally: blocks in my "controller" functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this assumes a lot about the environment the classes are being used in. In particular you assume that OP is using SQLAlchemy in the context of a Flask app using the FlaskSqlalchemy extension which provides that globabl `db.session` object.

If instead your models are part of a library, that _may_ be used in a Flask app, but also may be used in other contexts, it's not a good idea to assume this global session object is available. In these cases, you're probably better off parameterizing the session and passing it into your method from whatever environment you're calling it from.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is relevant to Flask-SQLAlchemy, but basic SQLAlchemy has examples of creating Mixin classes or augmenting the Base class.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html

e.g.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

class MyMixin(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB'}
    __mapper_args__= {'always_refresh': True}

    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class MyModel(MyMixin, Base):
    name = Column(String(1000))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would accomplish what you're after like this:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))

    def __init__(self):
        #self.name = name
        self.name = None
    
    @classmethod
    def add_user(cls, session, name):
        user = User(name)
        session.add(user)
        return User
```

Then in whatever context you're using it in, create a session, call your method, and commit it.

```py
from .user import User
session = Session()
# or if using Flask SQLAlchemy
# session = db.session
User.add_user(session, 'Foo')
session.commit()
```

From the [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it):

> Keep the lifecycle of the session (and usually the transaction) separate and external.

In contrast to one of the other answers, which assumes you are using this model in a Flask app with FlaskSQLAlchemy's global `db.session` object, parametrizing the session object like this keeps your model code separate from your session management code. This allows it to be used flexibly in many different contexts.